# Passing variable to Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I have a directive `myDir` and I call it within `ng-repeat` like so

```
<my-dir myindex="{{$index}}"></my-dir>
```

How can I access `myindex`? I get actual string `{{$index}}` when I use `attrs.myindex` within `postLink` function. When I inspect html, it actually says `myindex="2"`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try

```
<my-dir myindex="$index"></my-dir>
```

Then

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myindex: '='
    },
    template:'<div>{{myindex}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.myindex = attrs.myindex;
      console.log('test', scope.myindex)
    }
  };
})
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kaJk82mrTQD9QQdp2Gxz?p=preview)